# select only one value in 1:N relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to have only one value in the result of the query which is the first value, or the last value, i tried many things but i coudnt resolve it, the query is too long but i picked for you only the part where i am stucked.

```
    select eccev.extra_data , c.id, 
case when (eccev.extra_data::json->'tns')::VARCHAR = 'false'
    then 'NON'
    else case when coalesce((eccev.extra_data::json->'tns')::VARCHAR, '') = '' then 'EMPTY VALUE' else 'OUI'
end end as tns
from endorsement_contract_covered_element_version eccev, endorsement_contract_covered_element ecce, endorsement_contract ec, contract c, endorsement e, party_party pp 
WHERE ec.endorsement = e.id 
and e.applicant = pp.id
and c.subscriber = pp.id 
AND eccev.covered_element_endorsement = ecce.id 
and ecce.contract_endorsement = ec.id
and c.contract_number = 'CT20200909112'
```

with this query i have the result

```
{"qualite":"non_etu","tns":false}   199479  NON
{"qualite":"non_etu","tns":false}   199479  NON
{"qualite":"non_etu","tns":false}   199479  NON
```

i want to have only the first or the last row so i dont have repetition on the other rows, i saw that we can use first_value(X over (XX)) but i couldnt make it.

*if u guys can help me, i would be gratefull
Thanks*

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of the old syntax from 1989.

Comment: Try [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) with a subquery on the 1:many table(s):
`join lateral (select ... from sometable x where x.something = ... order by ... limit 1)`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select distinct on (eccev.extra_data , c.id) eccev.extra_data , c.id, case when ...
```

but your query seems not optimized as you cross join 6 tables all together ...

Comment: thank you every one.